# Update Session object item Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a cart session in laravel that looks like below:

```
{
  "5c10d896edd57": {
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "20.0",
    "dishId": "39508",
  },
  "5c10d8b55f34e": {
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "389.0",
    "dishId": "39510",
  }
}
```

I want to update the quantity if same **dishId** is added again
for this I have wrote this code

```
$previous_cartData = session('cart');
if(!empty($previous_cartData)){
    foreach ($previous_cartData as $key => $p_cart) {
        if($p_cart->dishId == $cart->dishId){
            $update_cart['quantity']= $p_cart->dishId+$cart->quantity;
            $request->session()->put('cart.'.$key, $update_cart);
        }else{
            $request->session()->put('cart.'.uniqid(), $cart);
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it replaces the whole object like this:

```
{
  "5c10d896edd57": {
    "quantity": "4"
  },
  "5c10d8b55f34e": {
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "389.0",
    "dishId": "39510",
  }
}
```

I only want to update the quantity without changing other keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because `$update_cart` doesn't hold any other values but *'quantity'*.

Try something like this:

```php
$previous_cartData = session('cart');
if(!empty($previous_cartData)){
    foreach ($previous_cartData as $key => $p_cart) {
        if($p_cart->dishId == $cart->dishId){
            $update_cart = $p_cart;
            $update_cart['quantity']= $p_cart->dishId+$cart->quantity;
            $request->session()->put('cart.'.$key, $update_cart);
        }else{
            $request->session()->put('cart.'.uniqid(), $cart);
        }
    }
}
```